# Date converted to str not slicing as expected

Tags: python, slice, python-datetime, strftime

Our organization runs a series of automations on a virtual machine which each output log files to shared folders when they run properly. I wrote a script to check for these log files each morning, but we've found a problem with it. The log files go to a folder with a name like `path/example-2023_04_01-06_30_01_AM.txt`.

Part of the script checks for files that are generated on a monthly basis like this:

```py
from glob import glob
from datetime import date

files = glob(path + "*" + str(date.today()).replace("-", "_")[0:9] + "*")
if len(files) == 0:
    print("Failed to locate this month's", automation, "file(s) at", path + "...")
else:
    print("Found and processed this month's", len(files), automation, "file(s). Logged at", files)
```

My issue is specifically with the `str(date.today()).replace("-", "_")[:9]` part. Using `[:9]` works for days 1-9 of the month but not for subsequent days. If it's `[:8]`, the opposite is true as days 1-9 look like `2023_04_1` instead of `2022_04_01`. I have also tried replacing `str().replace("-","_")` with `.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")` to the same results.

Why does `[:8]` cut off the leading `0` instead of the actual day prior to the 10th, and why does `[:9]` not work after the 9th? I would have expected `[:9]` to yield `2023_04_0` and `[:8]` to yield `2023_04_`. Am I entirely misunderstanding how slicing works or is something else wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "works" resp. "does not work"?

Comment: *I would have expected `[:9]` to yield `2023_04_0` and `[:8]` to yield `2023_04_`* – that's correct.

Comment: As a side note, the `str(...).replace("-", "_")` is an unnecessary hack. You can just format the date using your desire format from the start: `date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want my sliced string to be matched as identical to the filename. So, in this example, my slice should give me `2023_04_01` instead of `2023_04_1`

Comment: If you have `2023_04_01`, no slicing will give you `2023_04_1`. If you get `2023_04_1` after slicing, the string was something like `2023_04_1x` before slicing.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue. For me, it behaves as you expect. If what you want is to cut off the days, I would recommend using strftime like this: `date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_")`.

Comment: @Brian61354270 I use that more often. The other way is a remnant of a previous programmer

Comment: @mkrieger1 that's why I am confused- it *is* giving me 2023_04_1

Comment: How do you know that slicing gives you `2023_04_1`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 When I use `date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")[:8]` I get `2023_04_1` and when I use `date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")[:9]` I get `2023_04_01`

Comment: I don't believe that. The strings you claim to get are 9, respectively 10, characters long. And again, how do you know that this is what these expressions return?

Comment: @mkrieger1 hence why I am so confused. I don't understand why it's doing that either

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am printing them out to my console in lines omitted from the question for relevance

Comment: What do you get if you replace `date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")[:8]` literally by `"hello"`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think I found it thanks to you. There is another variable that is not behaving as expected- it is not the slicing but it appeared to be based on how I was testing it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I bet it was `"hello1"`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it was

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @mkrieger1, the issue was in a different part of the code and not in the slice itself. I followed the advice to try my test replacing `date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")[:8]` with `"hello"` and the result was `hello1`. When I wrote the question I omitted variables that I had thought were irrelevant which were actually the source of the problem.